# Highstocks candlestick and volume

Tags: javascript

I have Used Highstocks chart.I want the graph's xaxis date format to be represented in week or month or quater or year depending upon the user choice(given in radio button) . How can i do it?

Comment: Where is your code...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hdt9yqff/1/         my code. In this  i have kept the radio button for weeks,months,years,quaters

Comment: How can i control the distance between x axis and navigator in this